# openTSDB 1m-zimsum vs 1m-zimsum-zero

Tags: opentsdb

Encountered this when using openTSDB and I want to make sure I'm using the right function.
Difference of sum and zimsum is described here: http://opentsdb.net/docs/build/html/user_guide/query/aggregators.html
zimsum is suppose to add the data points together and fill zero if missing. I supposed 1m-zimsum and 1m-zimsum-zero should return same results. I have a single data logged in openTSDB once at 2 AM. I got a dot with 1m-zimsum but a line with 1m-zimsum-zero. Could anyone kindly explain?

I'm not super familiar with statistics and openTSDB. Please forgive me if stupid question is asked.
[image]

[image]